# Key1 IS defined, error saying it is not

Tags: python

I am running my code, and it does not work. However, that is not the problem. I defined "key1" and an error is coming saying

```
NameError: name 'key1' is not defined
```

I would appreciate it if someone could find the problem. I will post the full code below.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
choice = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? [e/d]: ")
string = ''

if choice == "e":
    message = input("Please insert the message you would like to use: ")
    keyword = input("Please insert the keyword you would like to use: ")
    for A in message:
        if message in alphabet:
            message1 = (ord(message)) - 96
        for A in keyword:
            if keyword in alphabet:
                key1 = (ord(keyword)) - 96
    addition = key1 + message1
    string = (chr(addition))
    print (string)
```

Comment: define `key1=''` at the top

Comment: @AvinashRaj Then `NameError: name 'message1' is not defined`

Comment: You are defining it **only** after a given condition is `True`. That error means that `keyword in alphabet` yields `False`. The same goes for `message1`. Double check your conditions.

Comment: What iled said. You _don't_ really want `if message in alphabet` or `if keyword in alphabet`.

Comment: The `for A in keyword` inner loop doesn't make sense to me. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Also you're donig `for A in message`, but never using `A` - so you're looping for no obvious reason. What are you expecting that loop to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `keyword` is not in `alphabet` then it will not be defined when you get to `addition = key1 + message1`. You can resolve this by setting `key1=""` before your conditionals or by having an else statement:

```
if keyword in alphabet:
    ...
else:
    key1 = ""
```

You should do this also for `message1` in the `if` statement above.

Comment: No problem. Could you mark the answer as accepted? Also, I think you need to take a look again at the loops. You're probably wanting to shift individual characters from the keyword rather than the keyword itself

Comment: Ahh, okay. How would you go around doing that? (I am quite new to coding)